# That chapter is a little further ahead

Tags: word-usage

My friend and I are reading a textbook. So she asks me about a chapter(she asks: Where is the chapter X?). I say:

> It is a little further ahead.

So,actually  we are on page 20 and it's  somewhere around on page 80/90 I'm not sure.

**So does my sentence sound natural?**

**And is the use of "where is the chapter X?" natural?**

Comment: We are on chapter 3. Where is chapter 10? (Note: No article with nouns that are immediately followed by a number or a letter). It's further in the book, between chapters 9 and 11, I believe. –

Comment: What about : It's a little further on.